# Django access entry from ManyToMany Through model in a template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-orm

I would like to access the list of users subscribed to a given training and I managed to get the list with correct number of subscribers but all subscribes have the name of the user currently logged in. Thanks in advance!

models.py

```
class Training(Base):
    subscribers = ManyToManyField(User, through = 'Subscription')

class Subscription(Base):
    user = ForeignKey(User, on_delete = CASCADE)
    training = ForeignKey(Training, on_delete = CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
class ShowSubscribers(Subscription):
    def get(self):
        self.subscribers = models.Subscription.objects.filter(training = self.get_training())
```

in my template I call the list in the following way:

```
{% for s in subscribers %}
      {{subscription.user.first_name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's `subscription` in your template? Try changing this:

```
{% for s in subscribers %}
      {{subscription.user.first_name}}
{% endfor %}
```

To this:

```
{% for s in subscribers %}
      {{s.user.first_name}}
{% endfor %}
```